# .Net Core 3.1 AWS Lambda error when passing Json in test body

Tags: c#, api, .net-core, aws-lambda

I am trying to test my AWS Lambda .Net Core 3.1 API.

I created a standard application using AWS tooling for Visual Studio and add my AesController. Standard Get request without parameters in body argument working fine, however when I try to call Get request with parameters I am getting "**400 Bad Request**" exception with *"The JSON value could not be converted to System.String. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 1."*

Test function:

```
[Fact]
    public async Task TestGetEncrypt()
    {
        var lambdaFunction = new LambdaEntryPoint();

        var requestStr = File.ReadAllText("./SampleRequests/AesController-GetEncrypt.json");
        var request = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<APIGatewayProxyRequest>(requestStr);
        var context = new TestLambdaContext();
        var response = await lambdaFunction.FunctionHandlerAsync(request, context);

        Assert.Equal(200, response.StatusCode);
        Assert.Equal("뺕結确᫷", response.Body);
        Assert.True(response.MultiValueHeaders.ContainsKey("Content-Type"));
        Assert.Equal("application/json; charset=utf-8",
            response.MultiValueHeaders["Content-Type"][0]);
    }
```

Settings Json:

```
{
  "resource": "/{proxy+}",
  "path": "/aes/GetEncrypt",
  "httpMethod": "GET",
  "headers": {
       "Content-Type": "application/json"
  },
  "queryStringParameters": null,
  "pathParameters": {
    "proxy": "aes/GetEncrypt"
  },
  "stageVariables": null,
  "requestContext": {
    "accountId": "AAAAAAAAAAAA",
    "resourceId": "5agfss",
    "stage": "test-invoke-stage",
    "requestId": "test-invoke-request",
    "identity": {
      "cognitoIdentityPoolId": null,
      "accountId": "AAAAAAAAAAAA",
      "cognitoIdentityId": null,
      "caller": "BBBBBBBBBBBB",
      "apiKey": "test-invoke-api-key",
      "sourceIp": "test-invoke-source-ip",
      "cognitoAuthenticationType": null,
      "cognitoAuthenticationProvider": null,
      "userArn": "arn:aws:iam::AAAAAAAAAAAA:root",
      "userAgent": "Apache-HttpClient/4.5.x (Java/1.8.0_102)",
      "user": "AAAAAAAAAAAA"
    },
    "resourcePath": "/{proxy+}",
    "httpMethod": "GET",
    "apiId": "t2yh6sjnmk"
  },
  "body": "{\"Data\": \"test_me!\"}"
}
```

API Get Function

```
    // GET aes/Encrypt
    [HttpGet("GetEncrypt")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetEncrypt([FromBody] string content)
    {
        var jsonConvert = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonAes>(content);
        var aesCrypt = new AesCrypt(jsonConvert);

        return Ok(Encoding.Unicode.GetString(await aesCrypt.CryptAes()));
    }
```

I believe that I am doing something wrong with my "body" argument in settings JSON. I tried to pass a normal JSON format without "" but I get the same error.

Comment: content-type should be application/json

Comment: ok, inside the header right? Now I am getting to respond "400 Bad request"

Comment: show the value of requestStr

Comment: is the same as "settings JSON"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I manage to find a solution.
I need to edit the get request function parameters to point to object rather plain string.

The correct code:

```
    // GET aes/Encrypt
    [HttpGet("GetEncrypt")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetEncrypt([FromBody] JsonAes content)
    {
        var aesCrypt = new AesCrypt(content);

        return Ok(Encoding.Unicode.GetString(await aesCrypt.CryptAes()));
    }
```

Comment: Let's keep comments civil and constructive please. Thank you.