# AWS Lambda API Application .Net Core Not responding

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, asp.net-core, aws-lambda

I created an AWS Lambda Application API using AWS Toolkit for .Net Core 3.1. It has 2 Get request that expecting text JSON in a request body and returning text JSON as an output. It does not require any database connection or any other AWS resources. Locally everything works fine, all tests are passing. I publish my app to AWS account using AWS Toolkit which runs Cloud Formation setting file, again no problems, all passing. This creates my AWS Lambda API app with my API endpoint. However, when I try to use I am getting **"403 Forbidden"** errors:
[image]

Other thing I notice is that the default API Gateway type is Edge, I am unsure if that's making a problem. I would like to set it up to Private in cloud formation stuck from .Net Core level. I assume it is something to be change here:

```
{
  "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
  "Transform": "AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31",
  "Description": "An AWS Serverless Application that uses the ASP.NET Core framework running in Amazon Lambda.",
  "Resources": {
    "AspNetCoreFunction": {
      "Type": "AWS::Serverless::Function",
      "Properties": {
        "Handler": "AES.Protocol::AES.Protocol.LambdaEntryPoint::FunctionHandlerAsync",
        "Runtime": "dotnetcore3.1",
        "CodeUri": "",
        "MemorySize": 256,
        "Timeout": 30,
        "Role": null,
        "Policies": [
          "AWSLambdaFullAccess"
        ],
        "Events": {
          "ProxyResource": {
            "Type": "Api",
            "Properties": {
              "Path": "/{proxy+}",
              "Method": "ANY"
            }
          },
          "RootResource": {
            "Type": "Api",
            "Properties": {
              "Path": "/",
              "Method": "ANY"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "Outputs": {
    "ApiURL": {
      "Description": "API endpoint URL for Prod environment",
      "Value": {
        "Fn::Sub": "https://${ServerlessRestApi}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/Prod/"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62772452/net-core-3-1-aws-lambda-error-when-passing-json-in-test-body) related to this API might be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to find a solution. It seems like CloudFront is not supporting GET request with "body". So changing "GET" to "POST" request fix the problem.